# Ob Buffering adding a number 1 to the end of the output

Tags: php

I have some perplexing behaviour going on within this snippet of code:

```
<?php
    ob_start(); ?>
        <script>
            jQuery(document).ready(function () {
                var the_instance = jQuery('.ib_clock_instance_<?php echo ib_clocks::$shortcodes; ?>');
            });
        </script>
        <?php
        $html = ob_end_flush();
?>
```

Which is part of a statically written class. For some reason a number 1 is being added to the end of the output put when `ob_end_flush` is called. It feels like it is probaly a boolean true given the php docs (http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-end-flush.php), but I don't see anyway to suppress it.

Anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: One thing to understand is that `ob_xx_flush()` func _will send_ the content to user, no matter what you're doing with the variable. You might want `ob_get_clean()` for just storing the content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ob_end_flush()` directly echos the output and only returns `true` or `false`, so when you echo your `$html` afterwards you'll get your `1`.

Either don't echo `$html`:

```
ob_end_flush();
```

Or use

```
$html = ob_get_flush();
echo $html;
```